# DynamoDB ConditionalCheckFailedException thrown but succeeds

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I think that have seen in many occasions that a DynamoDB conditional put throws ConditionalCheckFailedException but succeeds. Usually in this scenario, the request takes quite long (~10s) to finish, but I can see that the request is updated despite the fact that a ConditionalCheckFailedException is thrown (and the it took few seconds).

By the way I don't force any timeout on the DDB request.

Is this a bug, or some DDB conditional put contract that I misunderstand? Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Just saying that we might have also seen this on our DyDB where a request took about 5-6 seconds and then we got a conditional check failed; where the conditional check was that the record we wanted to insert didn’t already exist. So far as we can tell, it’s an impossible situation for us to get into with the checks before and the con-check was really a sanity check safety, the buck stops there. We only saw this once, in early July.
We can only think we have rogue code in our deployment we can’t find, or there was an issue in DyDB; both seemed impossible. 
Did you get anywhere with it?

Comment: I came up with some theory and got confirmation from a DDB engineer: this is expected extremely rare situation: basically your 1st attempt gets lost (i.e., a single host experiences a temporary network partition.) inside DDB services and was considered a timeout by the DDB gateway service, so your client would initiate a 2nd retry. However the 1st attempt wasn't completely dead inside DDB services and eventually succeeded before the 2nd retry writes the data, so the 2nd retry would get ConditionalCheckFailedException, which is then throwed by client. Note that AWS by default does 3 attempts.

Comment: Perhaps put that as an answer and I'll give you an UP
Also thanks @Yichao-Zhao

Answer (score 2):

*Answering this late to inform others:*

#### `ConditionCheckFailedException` but item is persisted:

This typically happens when you save an item to DynamoDB, DynamoDB acknowledges the write request but the response gets lost on the return path which can happen for multiple reasons, keeping in mind that DynamoDB is one of the largest distributed systems in the cloud.

This causes the SDK timeout to exceed while awaiting a response, which then triggers an SDK retry. When the write request is retried, the condition now evaluates to `False` as the item already exists, which in turn throws a `ConditionCheckFailedException`, which can cause confusion.

When I receive a `ConditionCheckFailedException` I typically do a strongly consistent `GetItem` request for the item to ensure it exists with the values I expect and move on.